# Why are the values being added on to my list twice each time? Issue in python

Tags: python, list, output

I'm having trouble getting the list for the heads and tails code I'm trying to write.

```
import random

list4heads=[]
maximums=[]
base=10

list4tails=[]
percent4heads=[]
percent4tails=[]
for exponent in range (1,6):


    ranges=base**exponent
    results=[0,0]

    maximums.append(ranges)
    for num in range (1,ranges+1):   

        flip=random.randint(0,num)
        if flip%2==0:
            results[0]+=1


        elif flip%2 != 0:
            results[1]+=1


    for slot in results:


        list4heads.append(results[0])
        list4tails.append(results[1])


        hp= results[0]/(results[0]+results[1])
        tp= results[1]/(results[0]+results[1])
        percent4heads.append(hp)
        percent4tails.append(tp)



print(list4heads, '\n', list4tails)
print()
print()
print(percent4heads, '\n', percent4tails)
```

I need each value to be added on once, but my output is looking like this.

```
[6, 6, 54, 54, 502, 502, 5053, 5053, 49746, 49746] 
 [4, 4, 46, 46, 498, 498, 4947, 4947, 50254, 50254]


[0.6, 0.6, 0.54, 0.54, 0.502, 0.502, 0.5053, 0.5053, 0.49746, 0.49746] 
 [0.4, 0.4, 0.46, 0.46, 0.498, 0.498, 0.4947, 0.4947, 0.50254, 0.50254]
```

Why is each value being added on twice? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The first 2 lines of the output are the times a "coin flip" landed on heads and then tails. It's first for 10 tosses then, 100, 1,000, 10,000, and 100,000. The next 2 are the percentages of each result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list `results` has two elements.  You iterate over it, but on *each* iteration, you update *both* the heads and tails counts, so they get updated twice (once on each iteration).  Remove your `for slot in results` and just unindent the code inside it so it only runs once.

Comment: Thank you! Thanks to everyone that answered too.

Answer (score 1):

You do

```
for slot in results:
```

and results has 2 elements.

This means that these two lines are called twice:

```
list4heads.append(results[0])
list4tails.append(results[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line:

```
for slot in results:
```